# What is this animal?

Tags: zoology, species-identification, entomology

[image: Red Black beast]

Can someone tell me what is the name of this one? Then I can check a little more about it.

Comment: How big is it and where did you find it?

Comment: It is not a beast :P

Comment: @RHA The bug in that question looks pretty different from this one...

Comment: @Cactuswoman same family, different species.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a squash bug to me ([*Pyrrhocoris apterus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrrhocoris_apterus)). If not *apterus*, I'd say it is at least in the *[Pyrrhocoridae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrrhocoridae)* family. Note, they must not but confounded with [Corizus hyoscyami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corizus_hyoscyami). Here is a picture of Pyrrhocoris apterus:

[image]

Pyrrhocoris apterus have a very broad range covering a big part of Eurasia, from France to China. Is it where you found it?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a species of the genus **Pyrrhocoris**, most probably the firebug [***Pyrrhocoris apterus***](http://bugguide.net/node/view/379064). Its quite common in Europe, but according to the [Global Biodiversity Information Facility](http://www.gbif.org/species/4486826) there are also some occurrences in the US.